# Rails override flash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, I often need to show several flashes, sometimes of the same type. In those cases, I do something like

*my_controller#some_action*

```
flash[:alert] = []
...
flash[:alert] << error1 if something_bad_happened
...
flash[:alert] << error2 if something_else_bad_happened
```

And in my view I iterate on each flash type and check if my flash is a normal flash or an array of flashes.

```
flash.each do |type, val|
  if flash[:type].is_a?(Array)
   flash[:type].each do |fl|
     render_flash(fl)
   end
  else
   render_flash(flash[:type])
  end
end
```

This is cool and works well, but in my code I end up with a mix of actions that use the standard flash and the "array" flash, and I find this stupid.

Is there a way I could override the flash setters so that

```
flash[:alert] = error_x
```

...would actually always push the error_x to an array of flash ?

**EDIT:**

The above code used for handling "array of flashes" is a quick way I found to achieve my goal, now if you're telling me this is too unclean and you have a better solution, I'm definitely taking it (or at least I'll keep it in mind when I have similar stuff to do in the future). I mainly put this code to explain a bit the context

**EDIT 2:**

> I end up with a mix of actions that use the standard flash and the "array" flash

I mean that for example, in some controllers I may have

```
flash.error = error_message
#or
render 'something', alert: error_message
# or
flash[:error] = error_message
```

Now, I am refining a lot of code, and somewhere else in a helper, I may want to show an additional error message, assuming the flash is already an array

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def my action
        if my_command_failed
          flash[:alert] = "Your command failed" # let's suppose it's the original []= method of flash here
           MyHelper::SomeTools.fix_stuff

        end
        redirect_to after_error_path
    end
end

class MyHelper::SomeTools
    def fix_stuff
      ...
      flash[:alert] << "Oh btw, there was also an error here..."
           # ... Which would normally crash, but I'd like to have some "clever code", which would fix the mistake for me (so making an array with both error messages)
    end
end
```

Comment: "create a custom handler", could you elaborate ? ALso, I actually use an array of flashes, because in my HTML I use one `<div class="alert alert-<%= flash_type %>>` per item in the flash array, knowing that a "flash item" can also include long text (where I use `.join()` and `<br>` tags already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given Eugene Petrov pointed out in his comment that flash messages can be any primitive, then you can consider to always make the value an Array if you feel the need to have Array in certain cases.

You can create a simply wrapper around flash in ApplicationController that forces the input to be converted and assigned to an array.

```
def multiflash(type, message)
  flash[type] ||= []
  flash[type] << message
end
```

And use it in your controllers.

In the view, simply pretend the flash to always be an array.

```
<% flash.each do |type, val| %>
  <% flash[:type].each do |fl| %>
     render_flash(fl)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you already noticed, it's not a good idea to have keys that sometime stores `Array`s and other times `String`s.

Comment: Yeah ok, but that still means I have to go over all my code again to use `multiflash` instead of `flash.alert = ...` or `render xxx, notice: "success"`

Answer (score 2):

You could try to redefine the `[]=` flash method, like this:

```
class ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
  def []=(k, v)
    k = k.to_s
    @discard.delete k
    (@flashes[k] ||= []) << v
  end
end
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html) and be sure to view the source code as well to not disable some functionality this method might have had you didn't think about.

You could place this bit of code e.g. in `/lib/flash_redefine.rb`, and require it where you want it or add it to `autoload_paths` in `application.rb`.

However be cautious, conventions are ment to be respected at least for readability sake, so this solution isn't clean or recommended.

Comment: Where should I put this piece of code ? In a separate file I should require in my config ?

Comment: A flash is designed to be a single string. If you need to show several flash for the same type, then either join them into a single comma-separated string, or create a custom handler. Trying to override the way it was designed may lead to several hard-to-debug and unintended side effects.

Comment: That's why I added a disclaimer at the end of the question. It answers the question, but question itself is asking for an unclean solution.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I was quite asking for an unclean solution, now if there is a nice clean solution that I can put in place, that wouldn't require too much effort, I'd say why not.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti flash doesn't have to be a stirng, see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L13), and i'd rather modify `render_flash` to hide this array or string logic. But overriding `[]=` is certainly not good way to do it.

Comment: Would it be better if, for example, I kept using a single string for flashes, but still overriding with something like `(@flashes[k] ||= "") << "#{custom_separator}v"`, where the separator is something I could easily detect to split the message afterwards when I render it ?

Comment: @EugenePetrov thanks for the link to the doc comment, I had missed it. Now I already hide the logic of the array/string in the loops that contain `render_flash` where I test for array or string.